# Can ophcrack crack credential files?

Tags: password-cracking, credentials

I have obtained some credential files from another pc and would like to decrypt them. These are the ones found under local/roaming profile in Appdata folder

```
 C:\Users\%USER%\Appdata\Microsoft\Credentials
```

Can ophcrack crack these credential files? I dont have any hashes, pwdumps or sam files.